# Scrape ASPX web form with wget?

Tags: asp.net, wget

For a data collection/analysis project, I am trying to download entries in a aspx web form at http://www.lasuperiorcourt.org/civilcasesummarynet/ui/?CT=AP&casetype=appellate, but I'm having little success so far.

The idea is to download the relevant information from the web page through wget and output the results to a single html file.  From the resulting output I would then compile stats on the extracted data on relevant cases (e.g. from case nos BV024000 to BV028933).

However, I'm having trouble getting wget to retrieve data from the form.  I've been using:

```
wget --post-data "frmsearch=BV024000" http://www.lasuperiorcourt.org/civilcasesummarynet/ui/?CT=AP^&casetype=appellate -O output.html
```

But I just get the original page back, not the form output.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two problems

1. You have typos in your command - you should wrap the http address between quotes and it's ui/index.aspx?CT=AP.  without the ^
2. When you post the form you have to post all the input fields of the form otherwise your post request is not validated.

Here I did the request as follow

```
    wget --post-data "__VIEWSTATE=%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%3D%3D&CaseNumber=BV024000&submit1=Search&casetype=appellate" "http://www.lasuperiorcourt.org/civilcasesummarynet/ui/index.aspx?CT=AP&casetype=appellate" -O output.html
--2012-08-12 19:25:32--  http://www.lasuperiorcourt.org/civilcasesummarynet/ui/index.aspx?CT=AP&casetype=appellate
Resolving www.lasuperiorcourt.org... 153.43.255.56
Connecting to www.lasuperiorcourt.org|153.43.255.56|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /civilcasesummarynet/ui/casesummary.aspx?CT=AP&casetype=appellate [following]
--2012-08-12 19:25:33--  http://www.lasuperiorcourt.org/civilcasesummarynet/ui/casesummary.aspx?CT=AP&casetype=appellate
```

and it worked see the picture http://i47.tinypic.com/35db8k3.png

Probably you will  need to set up a new value of __VIEWSTATE for every request.

Comment: Any idea how to batch process the input, i.e. batch posting every number from BV024000 to BV028000 and saving all the output to one file?

Comment: Well you could get an initial value for __VIEWSTATE - from your browser.
Then you can have a loop to call wget and increment the value of **CaseNumber** in  You could do directly in bash 

    `for ((i=24000; i<=28000; i+=1000)) ; do 
    wget --post-data "__VIEWSTATE=[YOUR VALUE]&CaseNumber=BV0${i}&submit1=Search" [OTHER OPTION AS BEFORE] ;
    done`

Comment: I'm having trouble inputting the correct __VIEWSTATE value.  I get the __VIEWSTATE value from my browser, but the same value doesn't seem to work with wget.  Are there any special URL encoding rules that I'm forgetting?  Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: maybe the various '%' need to be escaped if you are using windows but I don't know much about it.

Comment: I finally figured it out and got the correct value through the live http headers addon from Firefox.  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

In what environment are you executing this command?  In most unix shells, "&" is a special character which would terminate the command string and send the command, when executed, to the background.<strike>, but you aren't quoting that url in any way</strike>.

Edit:  Ok, nevermind... my answer isn't wasn't that useful except that I did not know that "^" was a quote character and now I know.  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: If there's something in particular wrong with this answer, please let me know. AFAIK, what I have provided is relevant.

Comment: I was using Win32 shell, so I used the ^ escape character.  Not responsible for the -1.